# Do we have a workaround to use alias with 'where' in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Sales :

[image]

Q1) Return the name of the agent who had the highest increase in sales compared to the previous year

A) Initially I wrote the following query

```
Select name, (sales_2018-sales_2017) as increase 
from sales 
where increase= (select max(sales_2018-sales_2017) 
                 from sales)
```

I got an error saying I cannot use increase with the keyword where because "increase" is not a column but an alias

So I changed the query to the following :

```
Select name, (sales_2018-sales_2017) as increase 
from sales 
where (sales_2018-sales_2017)= (select max(sales_2018-sales_2017) 
                                from sales)
```

This query did work, but I feel there should be a better to write this queryi.e instead of writing where (sales_2018-sales_2017)= (select max(sales_2018-sales_2017) from sales). So I was wondering if there is a work around to using alias with where.

Q2) suppose the table is as following, and we are asked to return the EmpId, name who got rating A for consecutive 3 years  :

[image]

I wrote the following query its working :

```
select id,name 
from ratings 
where rating_2017='A' and rating_2018='A' and rating_2019='A'
```

Chaining 3 columns (ratings_2017,rating_2018,rating_2019) with AND is easy, I want know if there is a better way to chain columns with AND when say we want to find a employee who has rating 'A' fro 10 consective years.

Q3) Last but not the least, I'm really interested in learning to write intermediate-complex SQL queries and take my sql skills to next level. Is there a website out there that can help me in this regard ?

Comment: The answer to the first two questions is to normalize your data.

Comment: Your main issue is that you have a bad db design, as it is now you will have to add a new column each year to your table. Instead ratings should be in its own table with columns `(year, rating, sales_id)`. This would certainly fix the issue you have with your first two questions. The third question is off-topic for SO and in the future only ask one question at a time.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single questions (especially not if some of those questions are off-topic)..

Answer (score 0):

1) You are referencing an expression with a table column value, and therefore you would need to define the expression first(either using an inline view/cte for increase). After that you can refer it in the query
    Eg:

```
select * 
  from ( select name, (sales_2018-sales_2017) as increase 
           from sales 
       )x
 where x.increase= (select max(sales_2018-sales_2017) 
                      from sales)
```

Another option would be to use analytical functions for getting your desired results, if you are in mysql 8.0

```
   select * 
     from ( select name
                  ,(sales_2018-sales_2017) as increase 
                  ,max(sales_2018-sales_2017) over(partition by (select null)) as max_increase
              from sales 
           )x
     where x.increase=x.max_increase
```

Q2) There are alternative ways to write this. But the basic issue is with the table design where you are storing each rating year as a new column. Had it been a row it would have been more easy.

Here is another way

```
select id,name 
  from ratings 
 where length(concat(rating_2017,rating_2018,rating_2019))-
       length(replace(concat(rating_2017,rating_2018,rating_2019)),'A','')=3
```

Q3) Check out some example of problems from hackerrank or https://msbiskills.com/tsql-puzzles-asked-in-interview-over-the-years/. You can also search for the questions and answers from stackoverflow to get solutions to tough problems people faced

Answer (score 0):

Q1 : you can simply order and limit the query results (hence no subquery is necessary) ; also, column aliases are allowed in the ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT 
    name,
    sales_2018-sales_2017 as increase 
FROM sales 
ORDER BY increase DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Q2 : your query is fine ; other options exists, but they will not make it faster or easier to maintain.

Finally, please note that your best option overall would be to modify your database layout : you want to have yearly data in rows, not in columns ; there should be only one column to store the year instead of several. That would make your queries simpler to write and to maintain (and you wouldn’t  need to create a new column every new year...)